# Drag and drop list alternatives for mid-age users

Tags: design, app

I wonder what kind of list ordering will be easier to use for 50+(age) users if there will be lists of 10-15 items. Also it is going to be used on touch devices too.
[image]

The idea is to arrange the documents before you start reading them.

1) the user will have a list of documents. 
2) On the "documents" list are the documents that are going to be read. "Optional" are the documents unassigned, that are not going to be seen when you start reading them. 
3) The user must be able to add,remove, change order of the documents.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean that user's age is 50+ years old? and they might not be accustomed to drag and drop experience on touchscreen devices?

Comment: exactly. Also there can be troubles with drag and drop on touch devices..

Comment: What evidence have you seen/read to suggest that users aged over 50 have trouble with drag-and-drop? I have not encountered this in any user testing (not that I have tested specifically for it).

Comment: Your initial premise - of age being an issue - is fundamentally (and offensively) flawed. Target instead specific limitations that people might be experiencing. To illustrate: Make it work for people with limited vision (and a 24-year-old woman I know with poor sight will thank you). Make it work for people with limited coordination (and a 36-year-old with Parkinson's will appreciate the effort). Make it work for people unused to touch screens (and have a think about who that might be). You can do this without being offensive to the 72-year-old retiree who built his own mouse in '83 for fun.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:** I think option C will help. However, you need to have only one ordering mechanism. Either use a drop-down list or the arrows. I would not recommend both. Multiple elements/ways to perform the same action might lead to confusion.

---

**Few points to mention**
Here are few points that I would like to mention:

1. I do not think user experience would suffer from drag and drop on touch devices. For example, Popular reader apps like MoonReader offer same experience with long tap & drag and drop. Check image:
   [image]
2. Taking "Age" as a critical criterion (and assuming that Drag and Drop experience would be difficult), I think simple directional arrows would suffice. tapping on up arrow moves the item above in the list and tapping down arrow move it's down on the list.
3. Operations like Add or remove a document should be placed on UI based on the frequency of use. If the actions are frequent then these options have to place on UI (probably in header or footer like a Floating action button). If the frequency of use is less then these options can go under a context menu.
4. You can also have a quick action as "Move to top" or "Move to the bottom", if applicable

Comment: What if we have like 15 documents, how are you going to drag the last document on the first position?

Comment: I just added a new version in my main comment, option C. What do you think?

Comment: If you mean that you want to drag the last document to first position which is above the fold then the list has to scroll along with the item that is being dragged. I recommend you try reader apps like moonreader. The image that I shared in my answer, in that app I have more than 40 ebooks. And yet drag and drop works fine.

Comment: I just saw option c. Will update on it.

Comment: updated answer, please check.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need an alternative to drag and drop, consider this:

1) Long tap on document selects it.

2) Short tap re-positions the document (above or bellow the tapped position, depending on the position of the second tap).

I believe this is a better alternative (albeit not as obvious) to forcing the user to tap multiple time on an arrow to re-position the document. Getting rid of those arrows wold also make to UI cleaner.

Just make sure to add enough visual cues so the user knows they entered "re-arranging mode" and possibly a small helper message with something like "Tap to reorder, back to cancel"

Comment: What if there are 15 documents, and I want to bring the document from the last position to first position. I tap 14 times?

Comment: No, for that long tap the last document to select it, scroll to the top, short tap above ou on the upper part of the fist document. No matter were you wish to move a document, it will always be three action at max: Select, scroll, tap.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this option for drag & drop.

[image]

In this option against each card, you will be having delete & edit option which allow to delete/edit the file. At the top, when the user clicks on re-order button it will open a modal/overlay which will allow the user to arrange the file in the way the user wants.

In addition to this, you can try out testing on earlier design to check whether people are able to understand the drag & drop functionality.

Let me know if you have any doubts.